# Get HTML content from textarea with TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have a problem with [TinyMCE 4](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) - I can't get HTML content from textarea. I am using the following code:

```
<textarea  id="tiny">some text</textarea>
    <a id="click" href="#">click</a>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#click").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var content=tinymce.get('content id').getContent();
               console.log(content);
           });
       });
    </script>
```

And as a result I'm getting this:

[image]

Question is how to get HTML content from `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the id of the `textarea` is `"tiny"` not `"content id"`...

`<textarea  id="tiny">some text</textarea>`

try changing...

`var content=tinymce.get('content id').getContent();`

to...

`var content=tinymce.get('tiny').getContent();`